# Set buttonColorNormal programatically for Android Button with AppCompat's design effect

Tags: android, material-design, androiddesignsupport

I have been using Google design support library for Android. In order to set colour of a button different from the app theme I declare the Button in layout XML file as follows:

```
<Button
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/MyButton" />
```

And then define the MyButton in styles.xml as

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

This gives me a button as per the design support library, with the background color as the one defined with `@color/my_color` in my colors.xml file.

Hence basically it is to use `android:theme` to change the `colorButtonNormal` attribute in order to get the desired color.

How could I achieve the same result programatically? Basically if I could do something like

```
myButton.setTheme(R.style.MyButton)
```

...then I could set the `colorButtonNormal` to get the view.

I cannot set the it like

```
myButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.my_color));
```

or not even like

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getActivity(), R.color.my_color);
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(myButton, colorStateList);
```

This will remove the design support library effect of touch.

Comment: did you try using setBackgroundTintList ?

Comment: @JEY
Followed the document but it didn't work. Updated the question for reference.

Comment: Your best chance might be to create the button programatically using one of these constructors:  Button(Context, AttributeSet, int defStyleAttr)
Button(Context AttributeSet int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)

Answer (score 1):

for Button I wrote this helper method:

```
public static ColorStateList getButtonColorStateList(Context context, int accentColor) {
    // get darker variant of accentColor for button pressed state
    float[] colorHSV = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(accentColor, colorHSV);
    colorHSV[2] *= 0.9f;
    int darkerAccent = Color.HSVToColor(colorHSV);

    return new ColorStateList(
            new int[][] {{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, {android.R.attr.state_enabled}, {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}},
            new int[] { darkerAccent, accentColor, getColor(context, R.color.buttonColorDisabled) });
}
```

accentColor is color value for normal enabled state. For pressed state is used darker variant of accentColor and for disable state I have defined color in values:

```
<color name="buttonColorDisabled">#dddddd</color>
```

Use this method:

```
mButton.setSupportBackgroundTintList(Utils.getButtonColorStateList(this, accentColor));
```

where mButton is AppCompatButton and accentColor is value of color.

This works for me on Lollipop and above with effect of touch and on pre-Lollipop as standard color change.

Comment: @PetrDana. 
Would it remove the ripple effect that we have on Button click on Lollipop and above?

Comment: @Tejas Ripple effect is kept.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one color (in spite of the state), you can use

```
Button button = ...;
int color = ...;
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(button, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
```

This will preserve ripple effect on Lollipop and newer devices (API 21+)